# how do I load length frequency histogram data into mixtools?

Tags: function

I want to use mixtools to separate 1, 2 and 3+ year old cohorts in shellfish length frequency data. I am totally new to R coding. The example is old faithful geyser data but it is merely a list of 272 data points. I have various tables of lengths (size class midpoints) and frequencies. Generally about 15 length classes and counts in each between 0 and 50. I can create a data frame from my MSexcel table but not sure how to call it with normalmixEM()  Thanks.